# Ubuntu 14.04 Clipboard Manager?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I'm looking for a program that saves the recent clipboard items (plain text would be enough) for Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: [Glipper](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/glipper/) is a popular choice.

Comment: Glipper works fine. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Done! Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Glipper was a clipboard manager, it was removed from Ubuntu and Debian in 2018.

For *buntu 20.04 several options are available:

- qlipper
- clipit
- copyq
- diodon
- parcellite

Comment: Thanks. For future users : please don't hesitate to add more good options, if any.

Comment: Ubuntu 16, no success.

Comment: the link is broken and I cant find Glipper on Software Center

Answer (score 35):

I use ClipIt is a Parcelite fork with Ubuntu menu integration.

```
sudo apt-get install clipit
```

It works on both, GNOME 3 and Unity.

Comment: Works on 16.04 LTS

Comment: I also found that [CopyQ](http://askubuntu.com/a/897671/167199) is more advanced than ClipIt. It has search on fly in saved copypastes.  And now i'm using CopyQ. [See my other answer below.](http://askubuntu.com/a/897671/167199)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/). It is easy to use and seems to be stable and reliable.

Comment: If you do decide to go with Keepboard then download the zip, extract it to its own folder, and make `start.sh` executable. Once you do that, it's easy to run and once you have it running you can make it run at startup with a simple checkbox in the preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using GPaste:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste
```

[image]

[image]

<sub>Sorry for the German screenshots</sub>

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore. Gnome, xfce, xUbuntu 14.04, April 2016.

Comment: It worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. You need to know the keyboard shortcuts though: Ubuntu > Settings > Devices > Keyboard > GPaste

Answer (score 3):

[CopyQ](http://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) is awesome advanced Linux clipboard manager.
It has tons of valuable features.

Install:

```
$ sudo apt install copyq
```

And add global shortcut:

Tray icon > Preferences > Shortcuts Tab > Custom Actions and Global Shortcuts.. > Add > Show/hide main window

Comment: Seems interesting. Unfortunately, it is not on 16.04 repositories, as I though on a first glance. On the web site, 18.04+ is mentioned, but anyway I can't add 'cause its repository is blocked by my company's policies.
Might be worth adding that you need to add repositories to your system to get it.

Comment: This question about 14.04 LTS message caused a similar question about 16.04 LTS to be flagged as duplicate of it:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/850209/clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu-16-04  There are other answers there, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Diodon](https://launchpad.net/~diodon-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable) is another good option available for both GTK and Unity. Works pretty much like the others in the answers already given. However, you can search your recent 'clips' using Dash.

As at this posting, it supports up to 15.04 - the latest version.

Install it with the follow

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install diodon
```

If you need the Dash functionality, you'll need a plugin for that.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-diodon
```

Then use `Super + b` to get the Dash scope.

Check out this [blog post](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/install-diodon-clipboard-manager-ubuntu/) for more information

Answer (score 1):

I use Clippy, a docklet that works with Plank (I don't use Unity). I think Clippy also comes with Docky.