# Paste as plain text using a clipboard manager

Tags: clipboard, text, paste, clipboard-manager

I need a global solution for paste as plain text function in my Ubuntu 16.10 system.

I know [CopyQ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/copyq/) has this ability but I want to use a clipboard manager which is [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software) and which can be installed from Ubuntu repositories. I prefer not to use a third party .deb file for a clipboard manager.

Could you please tell me which clipboard manager supports this function and how it is used?

For example, can I paste as plain text using [Clipit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkclipit/)? Can I define an "action" for that? If yes, how, please?

Comment: I've a clipboard manager project  ( originally written for this http://askubuntu.com/a/882821/295286 ) which allows for simple text manipulations and writing out text to a file, which goes there as plain text.  The project is FOSS ,  under MIT license. Since you mentioned you don't want third party `deb` , I'll assume you also don't want to add a third party PPA, so probably I won't post this as answer, but feel free to check out the project's GitHub page, source code is available there.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Serg : This sounds quite interesting. I will be watching your project. Thank you for letting me know.