# a painless way to copy and paste

Tags: gui

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 last week and find myself missing a paste tool on MacOS, [Paste – Cloud clipboard](https://pasteapp.me/)

It is a cloud clipboard helper, make a crisp sound  when perform copy and paste operations.

This is helpful especially works between emacs and the no-emacs text to ensure coping is successful.

Is there such a counterpart utilities on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called "clipboard manager". [I've made one](http://askubuntu.com/q/842386/295286) and there's also recommendations of other clipboard managers on the same linked post. However, most don't support pasting to the "cloud", and I wouldn't recommend doing that for security reasons.

However, you can either manually email the things you want, connect via remote connection to another device, or use public services like paste.ubuntu.com. Note also there's command line utility called [pastebinit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit) to post to the pastebin service directly.

Among other things, I would recommend reading [Arch Wiki article on clipboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard). Linux uses something known as X11 server, which in short is the graphical interface. There actually multiple selections ( or multiple clipboards, you could say ), and some of the clipboard managers can help you work much more easily with them.