# automatically log clipboard into logfile

Tags: clipboard

If something has been placed in the clipboard (CTRL+C or rightclick copy) is it possible to automatically log that into a logfile (append)? So someone can still read the clipboard from weeks ago?

Answer (score 0):

**Full disclosure: I'm the author of the suggested software**

Yes, possible with clipboard manager. It has to be on to record what is being placed into clipboard. If you want to review what was in clipboard from a week ago, but you had no clipboard manager running - there's no way to review previous information, as clipboard is not actively stored anywhere by operating system or desktop environment itself.

Specifically, I'd suggest [Indicator Bulletin](https://github.com/SergKolo/indicator-bulletin), of which I am the author, exactly because clipboard entries are timestamped, so you can search by time. Again, to review clipboard entries the software has to run to record clipboard.

Installation via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:1047481448-2/sergkolo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-bulletin
```

See other suggestions on another Ask Ubuntu question: [Searchable Clipboard Manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/842386/295286)