# Clipboard Manager for Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I'm looking for an application that can copy two or more items and then I can choose one of them to paste. Indeed, it should work on terminal.

Comment: Clipit is a great small utility, try it

Comment: It really is! @ArijitChatterjee

Comment: Did it work as you wanted?

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I just would like to have a shortcut to change from clipboards, but it is what I'm looking for. Now I discovered  that this kind of software is called "clipboard manager" and there is already one question on askubuntu about that

Comment: Diodon is a really good clipboard manager for Ubuntu. `https://launchpad.net/diodon`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**[Update on May 2020]**

**Clipit is now deprecated.** The official replacement is [Diodon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Diodon). To download Diodon, you can use the instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ediodon-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Clipit** is the best among all.

```
sudo apt-get install clipit
```

Launch it, one icon will appear on top right where you can choose one of your clipboards.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to filter/search the list using Clipit :(

Comment: Cool program.  Note that this is a blocking command, so if you want it to run in `~/.bashrc` or if you simply do not want it to freeze your terminal window while it runs:  Use `clipit &` to run it.

Comment: This now has a bug that prevents it from being usable https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt/issues/97.

Comment: Clipit is now [deprecated](https://packages.debian.org/sid/misc/clipit). The official replacement is [Diodon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Diodon).

To download Diodon, you can use the instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/~diodon-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

Comment: @hb20007 yes, hotkeys seem to be an issue. otherwise, it's a good alternative.

Answer (score 40):

**[CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/)** is a cross-platform, well-designed and fully-featured clipboard manager (my favorite). It features among others a (very handy) [command line interface](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/#command-line).

To install it on **Ubuntu 18.04+**:

```
sudo apt install copyq
```

To install it on **Ubuntu 16.04-**:

- Downloading a .deb file:

  - Download the correct `.deb` file from github: [hluk/CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/releases).
  - Perform installation:

    ```
    sudo dpkg -i copyq_*_Ubuntu_*.deb
    ```

Or

- Using a PPA:

  ```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hluk/copyq
  $ sudo apt update
  $ sudo apt install copyq
  ```

PPA info source: https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ#ubuntu-ppa

Comment: Add global shortcut:

Tray icon > Preferences > Shortcuts Tab > Custom Actions and Global Shortcuts.. > Add > Show/hide main window

Comment: this is the right and best answer :|

Comment: Took me a while to figure out this tool. It's has a lot of possible functionality. One of the best things I've ever seen through. Thank you!

Comment: Can someone compare and contrast clipit and copyq? from apt-get, Copyq is 2.5MB of archives and 10MB of disk space, while clipit is 149KB and 612KB respectively.

Comment: I think the idea is that clipit is gtk and copyq is qt, so me being on gnome it makes sense the former requires fewer things to get installed. Now, I will say this from my testing, clipit does not work very well. Hopefully copyq will get the job done.

Comment: I couldn't get the global short cut to display the clipboard. I didn't any of the extra features, so clipit worked better for me

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. My impression is that using copyq is like using hadron collider where you need a simple hammer. A hint about global shortcuts - first you go to Hot Keys tab and find there that F6 is for "Commands/GlobalShortcuts...". Then you click tray icon and select "show/hide" and the main window appears. Then you hit F6 and "Copyq commands" window opens. Then you click "+ Add" and select "Show the tray menu", assign a hotkey and apply changes. Voila. Now you can easily access the tray menu when you need to copy smth back from the clipboard. Clipit - install, hit Ctrl+Alt+H, done.

Comment: copyq supports images and clipit doesn't, if that's something you care about

Comment: Does CopyQ have this feature? https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/1149

Comment: Everyone, in case you click on it and it seems not to be opening, it's in the tray icons section! Or you can also use the `copyq show` command to show it.